# Solving system of equations over RR in sage

Tags: sagemath

I would like to solve a polynomial system over RR in sage. See the toy example below

```
>>> var_names = ['xor_0_7_x0', 'xor_0_7_x12', 'xor_0_7_y0']
>>> nvars = 3
>>> R=PolynomialRing(RealField(53), nvars, var_names, order="degneglex")
>>> a=R.gens()[0]+R.gens()[1]+R.gens()[2]
>>> b=R.gens()[0]-R.gens()[1]*R.gens()[2]
>>> s=[a,b]
>>> s=Sequence([a,b])
>>> s.solve()
```

I just defined two polynomial from $R$. But when I tried to solve this system I get AttributeError: 'Sequence_generic' object has no attribute 'solve'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
R.ideal(s).variety()
```

tells you that this has dimension one, so cannot be solved in the naive sense.